# Silverlight binding an collection with a collection inside

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, wcf-ria-services

I have an observable collection of Teams that are then bound to a RadGridview. No issues here. I am able to fill my grid with the team name in the first column. The second column is going to list the head coach. Inside my team collection i have another collection of KeyPeople which contains the head coach. so im struggling figuring out how to bind this second column to another collection.

i have this in my view model

```
TeamResults = new ObservableCollection<Teams>(_context.Teams);

KeyPeopleResults = new ObservableCollection<KeyPerson>(TeamResults.Select(x => x.KeyPerson).Where(g => g.RelationshipType == "Coach"));
```

but i cant bind my gridview to two different data sources. the TeamResults holds everything i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a client side property for your Team class.

All bindings for controls based off of ItemsControl bind directly to the individual objects showing in the list-and NOT the list itself.  This same concept continues to your VM: simply modifying your ViewModel won't help you either.  You need to modify the object itself to contain enough information for the binding objects you create in xaml.

Since you are using WCF RIA Services, you can create client side properties that does work for you.  Hopefully you are abstracting out your RIA services into Server-Side libraries and Client-Side libraries.

Simply make a partial of your Team class in the Client-Side library where the DataContext lives and write code similar to this:

```
public partial Team
{
    public KeyPerson HeadCoach
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.PeopleInTeam != null && this.PeopleInTeam.Any())
            { 
                return this.PeopleInTeam.FirstOrDefault(g => g.RelationshipType == "Coach"));    
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your binding you can simply bind to properties in Team:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" /> /*Team is implied as the object in each row is a Team*/
<data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HeadCoach.Name}" />
<data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HeadCoach.PhoneNumber}" />
```

This is a VERY common technique.  It is also the reason we have access to write client side code for the classes generated by WCF RIA services.

I've read your comments about using a separate query to load the head coach.  You might want to look into downloading your KeyPeople in the same query as your teams.  You can use an `.Include` statement on the server to send down the key people.

If this isn't a possible solution, then make HeadCoach a `{get;set;}` property in your ClientSide code.  Also, since WCF RIA is a navigational system, If you make the separate query on the SAME DataContext as the first query, the key people navigational system will already be setup, thus making your partial class' property automatically work.

Have fun!

Comment: I started to go the route of a converter..but this seemed to be a better fit for us. Actually a great lesson on both value converters and the client side changes that are made with Ria serivces..we are using the .Include in the domain services and this is exactly what we needed to do and will use in other areas of our application....thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to add a HeadCoach property to your ViewModel.  Have that property index the HeadCoach in the list.

If that is not posible, try using a value converter in your binding.  Something like this, please excuse the psuedo code.

`<Column Text="{Binding Path=KeyPeople, Converter={StaticResource FindHeadCoachConverter}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a data structure like `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`? It would be much easier to bind.

The `key` could be the name of the team and the `value` could be the name of the coach.

Comment: I like this direction but not only do i have to display the team name and the coach..but within that keyperson collection that holds the person data i will need to display the coaches name and all his contact information. email phone etc..

Comment: Well ok. Then it's just a little bit more complicated. You will need a ViewModel. Are you familiar with MVVM?

Comment: Well then design a `ViewModel` for this `View` and bind it to the grid.

Comment: In my viewmodel that i currently have for this view.. i have a  bunch of RIA service calls that get me the two observable collections in the initial question. I am doing a load of the Teams and doing an Include in the domain service that brings back keyPeople in this load call. so that observable collection of Teams also includes key people..within that key people entity is  a list of people and one of them is the coach.

Comment: I have no experience with RIA services. But your approach seems to be strange. I think the better approach would be to retrieve the data with their resolved relations (e.g. Team and Coach or Coach and his contact data). It would minimize the load on the client, because the server would do all the sophisticated stuff. It would also make the implementation of the frontend much easier.